# Need help in Regex to extract domains using Regex

Tags: regex, regex-group

Can anyone help to write a regex to extract domains like below:

If values are:

```
dns.google
x2.xdn.cbn.com
hello.1234.extra.net.com
```

then my regex should give output to me as below:

- `dns.google` --- no match
- `x2.xdn.cbn.com` --- extracts cbn.com only
- `hello.1234.extra.net.com` ---extracts net.com only.

I tried with negative lookbehind but failed.

Example: `(?<=\.).+`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Assuming that you have your input in a file called domains.txt and you would like to match the last two parts of each domain which has more than two parts, a grep-based solution could look like this:

```
grep -Po "[.]\K[^.]+[.][^.]+$" domains.txt
```